# Scala parser to parse scala?

Tags: java, parsing, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala AST in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788627/scala-ast-in-scala)

Do you know a java/scala parser what parses scala?

I want to do some code analysis on the AST.

Comment: You may find the new Scala macro/reflection stuff to be relevant to your needs.

Comment: compiler reloaded: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~magarcia/ScalaCompilerCornerReloaded/